# Get Data from Multiple pages of a Website

Tags: android

I am doing a android app that need to download data from multiple pages of a website. it contains pages like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5       next last. how can i handle this?

Comment: I used Jsoup parser. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Jsoup html parser(http://jsoup.org/). This is one of the well documented library.